Use multiple weight font file in Windows C# MAUI
I am using the Noto Sans font, which contains multiple weights in a single file, ranging from 100 to 800. In the Windows font manager, the font names appear as Noto Sans Light, Noto Sans SemiBold, etc. However, in MAUI, the "Label" control cannot specify the font weight. Has anyone successfully used this type of font file on Windows and specified the corresponding weight?
Yes I know I can use multiple files which contains one weight per file, and register them in MauiProgram.cs, but that costs too much disk spaces, it's the last choice.
Font Link: https://github.com/notofonts/noto-cjk/tree/main/Sans#downloading-noto-sans-cjk

You should add a comment to this issue: https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/16604

Fonts in maui do not provide an API to directly modify the weight. Maui
provides several options for setting whether the font is bold or italic.
